# Shifting a Button Animation using System.Windows.Media.Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, blend

I have a `Button` in my Window, how do I use code behind in C# to go about animating it to shift to the left by lets say 100 pixels once I click on it.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    DoubleAnimation _DoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    _DoubleAnimation.From = 0;
    _DoubleAnimation.To = 100;
    _DoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    myButton.BeginAnimation(Button.RenderTransformOriginProperty, _DoubleAnimation);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the size, in this case must be **`WidthProperty`** in Animation:

```
myButton.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, _DoubleAnimation);
```

To avoid *sharp* transition in the Animation, you must explicitly set the Width of the `Button`:

```
<Button Name="myButton" 
        Width="30" 
        Content="Test"  
        Click="myButton_Click" />
```

And in Animation specify only `To` value:

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation _DoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    _DoubleAnimation.To = 100;
    _DoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    myButton.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, _DoubleAnimation);
}
```

If you want to shift `Button` in Animation, you can use [`ThicknessAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.thicknessanimation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Thanks for the remark to `@Rohit Vats`

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0), 
                                                          new Thickness(100, 0, 0, 0), 
                                                          new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)),
                                                          FillBehavior.HoldEnd);

    myButton.BeginAnimation(Button.MarginProperty, animation);
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Anatoily I guess OP want to shift button to left by 100 pixels without playing with button's width. Atleast what I can infer from the question. So, I have posted my answer as well to shift the button but in case width is needed your solution works fine. +1 for you. :)

Comment: @Rohit Vats: Yes, I do not understand the question, sorry. Your solution is more suitable for OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you *want to shift button to left by 100 pixels*, you have to **set margin to -100 of last value** which obviously **can't be achieved by DoubleAnimation** since it can animate only double values whereas Margin is of type Thickness.

You can achieved that using **`Storyboard`**:

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
animation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, myButton);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
double left = myButton.Margin.Left - 100;
DiscreteObjectKeyFrame keyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(new Thickness(left,
                                             0, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
myStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

---

For **smooth transition** what you can do is **add multiple key frames and play them in interval of 0.1 secs**. In case you need more smooth transition, break it down to further smaller intervals.

This is how you do it:

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
animation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, myButton);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
for (int count = 1; count < 21; count++)
{
   double left = myButton.Margin.Left - (5 * count);
   DiscreteObjectKeyFrame keyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(new
                   Thickness(left, 0, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.05 * count));
   animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
}
myStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Hi when the animation starts, it just jumps from one point to the expected end point after 1 sec. I want a smooth transition.

Comment: @RStyle - Please see the update in answer for smooth transition.

Comment: great issit not possible to use double animation since it looks simpler in xml i thought i could be used in c#.

Comment: <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="myButton">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-100"/>

Comment: It won't be possible with `DoubleAnimation`. However, you can do that using `ThicknessAnimation`.

Answer (score 1):

It is depends how you have placed the `Button` on the page. If you want to layout elements by coordinates (not recommended) you can place the button on `Canvas`. Then you can use code like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Name="btnOk" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Click="BtnOk_OnClick">Ok</Button>
</Canvas>
```

and code-behind:

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(btnOk);
doubleAnimation.From = left;
doubleAnimation.To = left - 100;
doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
btnOk.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
```